# Slow speeds while copying large file in UBUNTU 18.04 Lts

Tags: 18.04, copy

I am Copying a large file in my USB DRIVE while copying more than half part it stucks and halt there while i cannot copy that file. I am trying this command

```
echo $((16*1024*1024)) > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_bytes
echo $((48*1024*1024)) > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_bytes
```

But it error-ed that.

```
bash: /proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_bytes: Permission denied
```

Comment: going to sound basic here but did you use `sudo` at the beginning of the command?

Comment: bash: /proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_bytes: Permission denied..Same error.

Comment: okay what account are you using to copy with? if you are not using root then you might not have the permision to copy.

Comment: can u explain me..i didn't get ur point

Comment: @RoboLover well certain accounts have certain level of rights so for example a guest account can't make new text files but a network user can make new texts files

Comment: @dsstorefile1 hey you never know how certain things are setup so always handy to ask

Comment: @dsstorefile1 that is true but as you say 'half part' so that could mean two things 1. robo has reached his disk use limit with the account he uses 2. he doesn't have the right level of privalige for the files

Comment: so what should i do regarding command ..i have read an article in which this error is resolved by above command...but when i run that command then error came

Comment: I have exact same problem. When I copy a video recording to a USB drive it sits there and nothing happens. This happens with every USB drive.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sudo echo $((64*1024*1024)) | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_bytes
sudo echo $((192*1024*1024)) | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/dirty_bytes
```

Also to ensure this fix stays after reboots add the following to your /etc/rc.local file, if it doesnt exist, create it.

```
echo $((64*1024*1024)) | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_bytes
echo $((192*1024*1024)) | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/dirty_bytes
```

Then make the rc.local file executable

```
chmod +x /etc/rc.local
```

Check everything works:

```
sudo systemctl restart rc-local
sudo systemctl status rc-local
```

Source:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107703/why-is-my-pc-freezing-while-im-copying-a-file-to-a-pendrive/107722#107722
- https://blog.programster.org/fix-freezes-when-transferring-files
- https://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/783/ubuntu-18.04-rc.local-file-not-exist-launch-with-systemd-rc-local